# Is it possible NOT to submit initial values of a multi slider using GET - javascript

Tags: html, forms, slider

I have a form to submit. I would like to use `GET` method for submitting so that users can save their searches.

Now, in this form I have two sliders (on the original page nicely mixed into a single one - but here I will not include CSS). By default, their value is always submitted. But I am not interested in submitting initial values: in my example 1 and 100 for `min` and `max` respectively. This means on the server side all the values so I wouldn't like to make another query to get all the results.

Is it possible to exclude initial (or, actually any desired) slider value being submitted through a `GET` method?

So if I click only on the `Test 1` checkbox and leave sliders at `0` (min slider) and `100` (max slider) as they are I would get the following string in the address bar of a browser:

```
example.com/index.html?test1=1
```

and not

```
example.com/index.html?test1=1&min=0&max=100
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class=w rapper>
  <form id="form" action="example.com/index.html" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test1" value="1" /> Test 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test2" value="2" /> Test 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="2" /> Test 3<br/>
    <div>Set minimum:</div>
    <input type="range" id="min" class="slider" name="min" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    <div>Set maximum:</div>
    <input type="range" id="max" class="slider" name="max" min="0" max="100" value="100">
    <div>Click here:</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I just didn't check the obvious solution – I apologize.

The below version actually works:

```js
let submit = document.getElementById('submit');

if ( ( (submit !== null) ) && ( (submit !== undefined) ) ) {
    if(submitFiltersButton.addEventListener){
       submitFiltersButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let minSlider = document.getElementById('min');
            if ( minSlider.value == 0 ) {
                minSlider.disabled = true;
            }
            let maxSlider = document.getElementById('max');
            if ( maxSlider.value == 100 ) {
                maxSlider.disabled = true;
            }
       });
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class= wrapper>
  <form id="form" action="example.com/index.html" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Test1" value="1"/> Test 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Test2" value="2"/> Test 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Test3" value="2"/> Test 3<br/>
    <div>Set minimum:</div>
    <input type="range" id="min" class="slider" name="min" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    <div>Set maximum:</div>
    <input type="range" id="max" class="slider" name="max" min="0" max="100" value="100">
    <div>Click here:</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <p id="submitted-data"></p>
</div>
```